# repeated measures within participant in lme4

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I'm trying to learn linear mixed effects models and how to estimate them using the R package `lme4` and I am confused about some aspects.

I have a dataset where a number of participants completed 6 trials for each condition in a 2 × 2 factorial design (`factor1` and `factor2`). I want to model intercept, slope, and interaction between factors as random effects. Following the software paper by Bates et al. (2015) for the `lme4` package and using their example as a starting point, I came up with this model:

```
response ~ 1 + factor1 * factor2 + (1 + factor1 * factor2 | participant)
```

What I'm unclear about is how to account for the repeated-measures character of the responses; within participant, responses for different conditions may be correlated across trials. There is no `trial` variable, just 6 different observations for each condition and participant. E.g. for participant 1:

[image: data for participant 1]

**Question:** Do I have to add something to my model to account for the correlation within participant between conditions across trials, and if yes, what?

Adding to my confusion, the conditional model in Eq. (2), i.e. within-participant in my application,
$$
(\mathcal{Y} | \mathcal{B} = b)
  \mathrel{\sim} \mathcal{N} \left( X \beta + Z b, \sigma^2 W^{-1} \right)
$$
includes a covariance matrix $\sigma^2 W^{-1}$, but the description says that $W$ is diagonal, i.e. it assumes observations within participant are uncorrelated.

In principle, the example analysis of `sleepstudy` in the paper has a similar problem: The reaction time measurements form a time series across days. However, in that case there is only one time series per subject, so there is no way to estimate these correlations (at least not without further assumptions like an AR process) – so I guess they don't need to be modeled?

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting to close this question? It is asking for help specifying a model, and the issues are clearly statistical rather than programmatic.

Comment: I agree that this question is more about accounting for the effects in the model then it is about R programming (and should be left open).

Comment: I read up a bit more, and apparently modelling of correlations within subject can be done in `nlme`, but not in `lme4`. Still I'm wondering why the authors of `lme4` chose an example data set which in my mind requires a feature that the package does not provide. – Does someone know whether there are plans for a package combining the features of `nlme` and `lme4`?